# How to use if condition in mongodb aggregate in node.js depends on the input

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

How can i add an if condition between the aggregate function, assuming I have one parameter from the request "input", if i have the input i would like to look id's greater than that id, if i don't have the input, i won't be matching the id, how can i achieve that?

```
collection.aggregate(
        // Pipeline
        [
            // Stage 1 
            {
                $match: {
                    "created_at": {$gte: fromDate, $lt: toDate},
                    "type": {$in : typeArray},
                    if (input){
                       "_id": {$gte: ObjectId("blahblahblah")}
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: // Equality Match
                    {
                        from: "users",
                        localField: "some_id",
                        foreignField: "_id",
                        as: "user"
                    }
            },
            {
                $sort: 
                {
                    "_id": 1
                }
            },
            {
                $limit: pageSize
            }
        ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this, for IF condition

> { $cond: { if: (boolean-expression), then: (true-case), else:
>   (false-case) } }

OR

> { $cond: [ (boolean-expression), (true-case), (false-case) ] }

for references you can have a look over the documentation

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: i only have a if condition without else, again that if condition comes from my input not from my database, i only want to match it if my input is true

Comment: then you can have a condition before your aggregate query